# Retrieving sub elements of xml using Xdocument

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I want to parse an XML file like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
    <database name="myDb">
      <table name="myTable">
        <field name="Code" type="int" size="0" identity="true" primarykey="true" description="کد شناسه" reference=""></field>
        <field name="Name" type="nvarchar" size="50" identity="false" primarykey="false" description="نام شخص" reference=""></field>
      </table>
      <table name="yourTable">
        <field name="Code" type="int" size="0" identity="true" primarykey="true" description="کد شناسه" reference=""></field>
        <field name="Title" type="nvarchar" size="50" identity="false" primarykey="false" description="نام شخص" reference=""></field>
      </table>
    </database>
```

The problem is that in my inner foreach it will parse 4 fields instead of 2 fields related to each table. how to change the code to read only the fields for current table?

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("d:\\tables.xml");
        foreach (XNode table in xdoc.Descendants("database").Nodes())
        {
            fields = "";
            tableName = XElement.Parse(table.ToString()).Attribute("name").Value;
            //XElement xE = XElement.Parse(table.ToString());
            //foreach (XElement e in xE.Elements())
            foreach (XNode field in xdoc.Descendants("table").Nodes())
            {
                fieldName = XElement.Parse(field.ToString()).Attribute("name").Value;
                type = XElement.Parse(field.ToString()).Attribute("type").Value;
                size = XElement.Parse(field.ToString()).Attribute("size").Value;
                identity = XElement.Parse(field.ToString()).Attribute("identity").Value;
                primarykey = XElement.Parse(field.ToString()).Attribute("primarykey").Value;
                description = XElement.Parse(field.ToString()).Attribute("description").Value;
                reference = XElement.Parse(field.ToString()).Attribute("reference").Value;

                if (identity == "true") identity = "identity";
                if (primarykey == "true") primarykey = "primary key";

                if (isChar(type))
                {
                    fields += string.Format(fieldCharTemplate, fieldName, type, size);
                }
                else
                {
                    fields += string.Format(fieldNonCharTemplate, fieldName, type, identity,primarykey);
                }
                //var y = x.Element("type");
            }
            sql = string.Format(tableTemplate, tableName, fields);
            Response.Write(sql);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
foreach (XNode field in xdoc.Descendants("table").Nodes())
```

That's looking for *all* nodes under *all* `table` elements. You don't want that.

You've already *got* the table you're looking at as an `XElement` - so use that. It requires that your `table` variable is an `XElement` rather than just `XNode`, but that's what you really want anyway... and it means you don't have to reparse it to get the table name. I would write your code as:

```
foreach (XElement table in xdoc.Root.Elements("table"))
{
    string tableName = (string) table.Attribute("name");
    StringBuilder fields = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (XElement field in table.Elements("field"))
    {
        string fieldName = (string) field.Attribute("name");
        string type = (string) field.Attribute("type");
        // Consider casting to int instead...
        string size = (string) field.Attribute("size");
        bool identity = (bool) field.Attribute("identity");
        bool primaryKey = (bool) field.Attribute("primarykey");
        string description = (string) field.Attribute("description");
        string reference = (string) field.Attribute("reference");
        // Append to fields here
    }
}
```

Note how much simpler it is to get to the attributes when you already have an element. You really shouldn't need to do multiple parse operations in the vast majority of cases. Also note how I've used the conversion to `bool` for `primarykey` and `identity`. Again, this is cleaner than testing the string manually.

Answer (score 1):

Here is correct way for parsing your xml. Tables and fields are elements, so get them as elements:

```
   // instead xdoc.Descendants("database").Nodes()
   xdoc.Descendants("table") // returns all table elements
```

Also use casting when getting elements or attribute values. It will not throw exception if node not found, and it will simplify your code if you need parsing to bool, integer etc:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("d:\\tables.xml");
foreach (XElement table in xdoc.Root.Elements("table"))
{
    tableName = (string)table.Attribute("name");

    foreach (XElement field in table.Elements("field"))
    {
        fieldName = (string)field.Attribute("name");
        type = (string)field.Attribute("type");
        size = (int)field.Attribute("size"); // that will be an integer
        identity = (bool)field.Attribute("identity"); // boolean
        primarykey = (bool)field.Attribute("primarykey"); // boolean
        description = (string)field.Attribute("description");
        reference = (string)field.Attribute("reference");
        // ...
    }

}
```

I suggest you to read [Querying XML Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387050.aspx) articles.

Answer (score 0):

Use XElement instead of XNode.